# How to make div not jump to next line, but fluid instead? when browser resizes

Tags: html, css

How do I keep the purple div from jumping to the next line? I want the text to stay fluid and not jump to the next line when browser resizes. Meaning the green and purple div will stay inline no matter what.

Here is what I have so far - https://jsfiddle.net/Ljcu1hyw/

Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but I must be missing something here and just need a second opinion.

Thanks for your time folks!

```
.marco-maggio {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f0f0ef;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 80px 0px 100px 0px;
}

.marco-maggio .profile-wrapper {
  background: #FFBFBF;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1130px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.profile {
  height: 100%;
  width: 340px;
  background: #DFFFBF;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}

.description {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 780px;
  background: #DFBFFF;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 20px;
  Float: right;
}
.description h1 {font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-size: 34px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700;}
.description h2 {font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif; font-size: 20px; font-style: italic; margin-top: 5px;}
.description span {font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; display: inline-block; margin-top: 50px;}

.profilepic {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #80BDFF;
}

.profile-span {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have a `width: 100%` for the `.description` class.

Instead of 100% I would try:

```
.description {
    width: calc(100% - 340px); //340px is the width of the .profile, and you want to subtract that from the total width of 100%
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Totally forgot you could do that. Thanks mate :)